# 2-D numpy array with tuples: expanding into multiple arrays w/combinations of original tuples

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy array like the following:

```
0      1      (2,3)
(4,5)  6      7
9      (10,)  11
```

How could I split it a list of the arrays below? Conditions: no tuples in final arrays, and each array contains a unique combination of the tuple elements. That is, there are two tuples in the original array, so there are 4 different combinations of those elements. The first array below has the combination (2) and (4) from the original.

```
0  1  2
4  6  7
9  10 11

0  1  2
5  6  7
9  10 11

0  1  3
4  6  7
9  10 11

0  1  3
5  6  7
9  10 11
```

Comment: Can we try to solve the problem before it reaches this stage? How was the original array created?

Comment: The original array was created by lookups of array elements in a dictionary (w/ arbitrary length values), which explains the tuples in awkward places. I'll try to refactor the code, as you suggested.

Comment: If you generate a tuple at *every* location, then you could pass the  sequence of tuples to `itertools.product` which could then generate the final result fairly cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a data structure is awkward, as @unutbu suggested. But if you want to do it, it is doable:

```
In [52]:
A
Out[52]:
array([[0, 1, (2, 3)],
       [(4, 5), 6, 7],
       [9, (10,), 11]], dtype=object)

In [53]:
import itertools
AR=A.ravel()
AT=[i for i, val in enumerate(AAR) if isinstance(val, tuple)]
for item in itertools.product(*AR[AT]):
    B=AR.copy()
    B[AT]=item
    print B.reshape(A.shape)
[[0 1 2]
 [4 6 7]
 [9 10 11]]

[[0 1 2]
 [5 6 7]
 [9 10 11]]

[[0 1 3]
 [4 6 7]
 [9 10 11]]

[[0 1 3]
 [5 6 7]
 [9 10 11]]
```